# custom tag in JSP

Tags: java, jsp-tags

when i'm using custom tag in JSP using taglib
the attribute type must be string
(and can be change in the class with the logic to another type)
or there is a way to use pther stuff then string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute types can be set in the TLD by adding a [type element](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html#bnani).

The specifics for the latest version are covered in the [JSP 2.2 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html).